# Consumiendo una api node con react el post rompe la app

Tags: mysql, nodejs, reactjs, express, sequelize

Tengo una aplicación Node con Express Sequelize y una bd Mysql corriendo en docker. Todo funciona bien hasta acá, comprobado con postman.
Pero cuando consumo la aplicación Node con React el POST me devuelve parámetros vacíos y se rompe.

No estoy seguro de qué parte del código compartir, pero este es el código que hace el post en el form en React:

```
let{nombre, descripcion, precio, imageUrl, marcaId} = product

    const handleSubmit = () => {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(product))
        precio = parseInt(precio, 10) 
        //Validación de datos
        if (nombre === '' || descripcion === '' || precio <= 0 || imageUrl === '' || marcaId !== '1' ) {
            alert('Todos los campos son obligatorios')
            return 
        }

        //Consulta
        const requestInit = {
            method: 'POST',
            header: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(product)
        }
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/productos/add', requestInit)

        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        alert(JSON.stringify(requestInit))

      }
```

El error que me devuelve la api Node al momento de realizar un POST:

```
notNull Violation: productos.descripcion cannot be null,
notNull Violation: productos.precio cannot be null,
notNull Violation: productos.imageUrl cannot be null
...
```

Con Sequelize realicé una relación de pertenencia entre Productos y Marcas:

```
Productos.belongsTo(Marcas)
```

Comment: Estás en [es.so]. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. De paso, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta, incluyendo el título de tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, reformula tu pregunta en castellano.

Comment: ¡No olvides traducir además el título!

Answer (score 1):

ya lo resolvi, el problema estaba en el form, entiendo que en lo publicado le estaba pasando un objeto al JSON.stringify cuando tenia que mapearle los datos

```
//Consulta
        const requestInit = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "nombre":product.nombre,
                "descripcion":product.descripcion,
                "precio":product.precio,
                "imageUrl":product.imageUrl,
                "marcaId":product.marcaId
            })
        }
```

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada! Así se marca que lo solucionaste, no con el título :)